# There are some updates showing up in my 'Apt-update indicator' but nothing is updated when i try update and upgrade in terminal

Tags: system-installation

In my apt-update extension for gnome, there are 3 updates pending. They are  `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`
`linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04` and 
`linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04`

When I run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` I find 
`The following packages have been kept back:
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04`

Then again when I run this `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04`, it prompted me for a download of 326 MB of data to download.

What are these actually? And do i need to install them? If not how to avoid them like removing their entry from anywhere or something like that?

Comment: these packages are updates to the linux kernel.  You might have broken dependencies.  You can run `sudo apt-get check` to see.  You may need to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get -f install` to automatically remove outdated packages and to attempt to correct broken dependencies.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get dist-update`

Comment: @cmak.fr It should be `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

```
linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

is the metapackage that upgrades the kernel and kernel-headers from Kerneltree 4.18.

If you have more than 1 metapackage on your system you get more kernel-packages than you need. Control which is the current one by runnnig `uname -a` Identify which metapackages are on your system. `dpkg -l | fgrep linux-generic`